# how to indent the lines in file + bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, printf

I have many files like the following ( the same concept on all the files )

```
 more list-OS23

 linux-d
 linux-01  fedora-linux-c
 Solaris_machine1
 AIX-65             linux-redhat18   unixware7-h  unix-digital
       linux56-a     linuxr9
```

my target is to indent the lines as the following format order

```
 more list-OS23


 cycel 1             cycel2             cycel3         cycel4


 linux-d             fedora-linux-c     unixware7-h    unix-digital
 linux-01            linux-redhat18
 Solaris_machine1    linuxr9        
 AIX-65               
 linux56-a
```

I try to indent the file/s by awk

```
  awk '{print $1"  "$2"   "$3}'  file
```

but the indentation not as I expected

can I get idea or real example how to indent the file?

I think printf is good command for this propose

Comment: The input doesn't match the output, some things, like `Solaris_machine1` are missing from the output, and `cycel1` etc. is missing from the input (are these to be added?). Also, rows seems to swap places in a way that is unspecified.

Comment: I fixed the lines - sorry

Comment: Are also wanting to fill the columns? I'm not sure how items (`unixware7-h` and others) can jump between lines otherwise.

Comment: they need to start from up to down as example said  ( no need to filll the column )

Comment: Yes, printf is good. eg `declare -a array; read -r -a array; for i in "${array[@]}"; do printf '%-12s' "$i"; done`

Comment: ok  - so can you please described  your suggestion as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk '
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        rowNr = ++rowNrs[i]
        colNr = ++colNrs[rowNr]
        vals[rowNr,colNr] = $i
        numCols = (NF > numCols ? NF : numCols)
    }
}
END {
    for (colNr=1; colNr <= numCols; colNr++) {
        printf "cycle%s%s", colNr, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr <= NR; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; (rowNr,colNr) in vals; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", (colNr>1 ? OFS : ""), vals[rowNr,colNr]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
' "$1" | column -t

$ ./tst.sh file
cycle1            cycle2          cycle3       cycle4
linux-d           fedora-linux-c  unixware7-h  unix-digital
linux-01          linux-redhat18
Solaris_machine1  linuxr9
AIX-65
linux56-a
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe in AWK:

```
$ cat > test.awk
BEGIN {
FS="( +)"  # input field separator is a bunch of spaces
OFS="\t"   # output separator is tab
}
NR==1 {    # just print the first line as is
    print $0
}
{          # the rest are re-delimited and printed
    $1=$1
    print $0
}

$ awk -f test.awk your_input.in
```

or as a one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="( +)";OFS="\t"}NR==1 {print $0;}{$1=$1;print $0}' your_input.in
```

.

Comment: By default awk will squeeze spaces and tabs when splitting to fields: `a<space><space>b` will store `a` in `$1` and `b` in `$2`

Comment: Also `NR==1{print $0}` is the same as `NR==1`. Your whole awk could be written as: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS='\t'}NR>1{$1=$1}1' input.txt` or `awk 'NR>1{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t' input.txt` assuming you don't want to print the first line twice

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file.txt
linux-d
 linux-01  fedora-linux-c
 Solaris_machine1
 AIX-65             linux-redhat18   unixware7-h  unix-digital
       linux56-a     linuxr9

$ cat a.awk
$1 != "" { ac1[++c1] = $1 }
$2 != "" { ac2[++c2] = $2 }
$3 != "" { ac3[++c3] = $3 }
$4 != "" { ac4[++c4] = $4 }
END {
    for (i=1; i<=length(ac1); ++i) {
        printf "%s %s %s %s\n", ac1[i],ac2[i],ac3[i],ac4[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f a.awk file.txt | column -c 4 -t
linux-d           fedora-linux-c  unixware7-h  unix-digital
linux-01          linux-redhat18
Solaris_machine1  linuxr9
AIX-65
linux56-a
```

Comment: is it possible to run it from the bash script (inside the bash script )

Comment: Yes, of course. (The pipe to `column` is optional if you don't care about the formatting.)

Comment: ok so can you please change your code so I will run it from my bash script ?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you can't put the awk script in a separate file?

Comment: yes I need to write it inside the bash script and not as ext awk code

Comment: You should really test for `$4!=""` instead of just `$4`, etc. as the latter will fail when awk encounters a `$4` value it thinks evaluates numerically to zero. You don't need to squeeze the awk script onto one line to use it inside a shell script. Just delimit it as written with `awk 'contents of a.awk' file`.

Comment: All good points, @EdMorton. I've never been sure if spreading single-quoted values across multiple lines works in all shells.

Comment: @jas yes it does work in all shells and the only difference between `awk 'inlineScript' inputFile` and `awk -f scriptFile inputFile` is that you can't have any `'`s in an inline script, even in comments, so you should use `\047`s instead.